# Graph with multiple boxplots using Python

Tags: python, csv

I am currently coding using Python in Google Collab. I am working with underwater glider data that I have uploaded via url from NOAA's ERDDAP site.

```
url = 'https://gliders.ioos.us/erddap/tabledap/ru28-20150917T1300.csv?profile_id%2Ctime%2Clatitude%2Clongitude%2Cdepth%2Ctemperature%2Csalinity%2Cdensity&time%3E=2015-09-18T00%3A00%3A00Z&time%3C=2015-10-06T00%3A00%3A00Z'

url2 = 'https://gliders.ioos.us/erddap/tabledap/ru28-20140815T1405.csv?profile_id%2Ctime%2Clatitude%2Clongitude%2Cdepth%2Ctemperature%2Csalinity%2Cdensity&time%3E=2014-08-16T00%3A00%3A00Z&time%3C=2014-09-04T00%3A00%3A00Z'

url3 = 'https://gliders.ioos.us/erddap/tabledap/ru28-20130813T1436.csv?profile_id%2Ctime%2Clatitude%2Clongitude%2Cdepth%2Ctemperature%2Csalinity%2Cdensity&time%3E=2013-08-14T00%3A00%3A00Z&time%3C=2013-08-26T00%3A00%3A00Z'

url4 = 'https://gliders.ioos.us/erddap/tabledap/blue-20200819T1433.csv?profile_id%2Ctime%2Clatitude%2Clongitude%2Cdepth%2Ctemperature%2Csalinity%2Cdensity&time%3E=2020-08-19T00%3A00%3A00Z&time%3C=2020-08-25T00%3A00%3A00Z'

url5 = 'https://gliders.ioos.us/erddap/tabledap/blue-20190815T1711.csv?profile_id%2Ctime%2Clatitude%2Clongitude%2Cdepth%2Ctemperature%2Csalinity%2Cdensity&time%3E=2019-08-16T00%3A00%3A00Z&time%3C=2019-09-24T00%3A00%3A00Z'

url6 = 'https://gliders.ioos.us/erddap/tabledap/blue-20180806T1400.csv?profile_id%2Ctime%2Clatitude%2Clongitude%2Cdepth%2Ctemperature%2Csalinity%2Cdensity&time%3E=2018-08-07T00%3A00%3A00Z&time%3C=2018-10-31T00%3A00%3A00Z'

url7 = 'https://gliders.ioos.us/erddap/tabledap/blue-20170831T1436.csv?profile_id%2Ctime%2Clatitude%2Clongitude%2Cdepth%2Ctemperature%2Csalinity%2Cdensity&time%3E=2017-09-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&time%3C=2017-09-24T00%3A00%3A00Z'
```

I then loaded the datasets:

```
data1 = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
data2 = pd.read_csv(url2, skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
data3 = pd.read_csv(url3, skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
data4 = pd.read_csv(url4, skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
data5 = pd.read_csv(url5, skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
data6 = pd.read_csv(url6, skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
data7 = pd.read_csv(url7, skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
```

And combined them into one dataframe:

```
combined_df = pd.concat([data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7], axis = 0)
```

Running the line `combined_df.head()` gives a preview of the data as such:

```
                       profile_id   latitude longitude depth temperature salinity   density
time                            
2015-09-18 00:02:41+00:00   81  40.350986   -73.871552  20.09   14.0286 32.678837   1024.4777
2015-09-18 00:02:41+00:00   81  40.350986   -73.871552  20.73   13.8871 32.658794   1024.4943
2015-09-18 00:02:41+00:00   81  40.350986   -73.871552  21.05   13.8069 32.680794   1024.5292
2015-09-18 00:04:36+00:00   82  40.350817   -73.871420  21.05   13.8069 32.680794   1024.5292
2015-09-18 00:16:07+00:00   83  40.349812   -73.870636  20.76   13.9284 32.670765   1024.4951
```

I need to make a graph with 7 individual boxplots with values from each dataset. I am focusing on temperature, salinity, and density. The x axis would be time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When combining them you lose the information what datapoint belongs to which dataset. How did you want to address this? When you say, you want to plot temperature, salinity,  and density, should they be [three panels of the same figure with a shared x-axis](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/shared_axis_demo.html) or [in the same figure](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/axisartist/demo_parasite_axes.html)? Even more so, I have difficulties understanding what 7 individual boxplots over time look like. Can you link to an example or draw a figure and post it here?

Comment: That's part of the issue I'm facing, I'm unsure if I should use the individual datasets instead of the combined one. [This box plot](https://www.google.com/search?q=graph+with+multiple+boxplots&sxsrf=ALeKk01MGod_epp1lOoKSN5AZdlS0RKtbg:1607109581750&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjssfDdhbXtAhWwmuAKHXsZDigQ_AUoAXoECBUQAw&biw=1440&bih=765&dpr=2#imgrc=NLTJhd2EPkMf9M) is an example of what I am going for, with the days on the x axis representing the years of my datasets. Let me know if that makes more sense.

Comment: So, you want an annually grouped boxplot for each of the dataframes, and this for the three categories temperature, salinity, and density? Well, you can combine them but at least introduce a new column `data1["ID"]=1`, `data2["ID"]=2`, etc., so you still know where the data originated. Given this rather complex task, you might want consider [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) which takes away a lot of the problems you encountered if you did it with matplotlib. (and introduces other problems but more about that later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems that each file contains the data of one year, we can simplify the approach, and [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) is of great help here. To make the code more readable (read: because we are too lazy to type repetitive things), we put these tasks into loops and store the necessary variables in lists.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

url = 'https://gliders.ioos.us/erddap/tabledap/ru28-20150917T1300.csv?profile_id%2Ctime%2Clatitude%2Clongitude%2Cdepth%2Ctemperature%2Csalinity%2Cdensity&time%3E=2015-09-18T00%3A00%3A00Z&time%3C=2015-10-06T00%3A00%3A00Z'    
url2 = 'https://gliders.ioos.us/erddap/tabledap/ru28-20140815T1405.csv?profile_id%2Ctime%2Clatitude%2Clongitude%2Cdepth%2Ctemperature%2Csalinity%2Cdensity&time%3E=2014-08-16T00%3A00%3A00Z&time%3C=2014-09-04T00%3A00%3A00Z'    
url3 = 'https://gliders.ioos.us/erddap/tabledap/ru28-20130813T1436.csv?profile_id%2Ctime%2Clatitude%2Clongitude%2Cdepth%2Ctemperature%2Csalinity%2Cdensity&time%3E=2013-08-14T00%3A00%3A00Z&time%3C=2013-08-26T00%3A00%3A00Z'

urls = [url, url2, url3]  #<---add the remaining urls, this example is just for three of them
#because the download takes a while, we can simulate this with already downloaded files
#urls=["ru28-20140815T1405_0c34_1256_e732.csv", "ru28-20150917T1300_cc34_de4b_4c02.csv", "ru28-20130813T1436_5a0d_6ca1_4df0.csv"]

print("started loading")
#load file 1 into a dataframe and extract year as its identifier
combined_df = pd.read_csv(urls[0], skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
combined_df["year"] = combined_df.index.year
#we could also add another identifier in case years overlap between files
#combined_df["data_ID"] = 1
print("data file 1 is ready")

#load one url after the other and append it to the combined dataframe
for i, curr_url in enumerate(urls[1:]):
    tmp_data = pd.read_csv(curr_url, skiprows=[1], parse_dates=['time'], index_col='time')
    tmp_data["year"] = tmp_data.index.year
    #tmp_data["data_ID"] = i+2
    combined_df = pd.concat([combined_df, tmp_data], axis = 0)
    print(f"data file {i+2} is ready")

print("finished downloads")
print("plotting now")

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, figsize=(8, 10))

sns.set_theme(style="ticks", palette="pastel")

categ = ["temperature", "density", "salinity"]    
cat_color = ["grey", "tab:orange", "yellow"]

for i, curr_ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    sns.boxplot(x="year", y=categ[i], data=combined_df, color=cat_color[i], ax=curr_ax)
    sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True, ax=curr_ax)

plt.tight_layout(h_pad=2)
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: thank you so much for explaining it in depthj!

Comment: I suggest spending some time with [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/index.html) and [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html#plotting) tutorials to better understand the logic of these tools. Pandas uses matplotlib for plotting. Seaborn is often quite helpful but it is built on top of matplotlib, so an understanding of matplotlib is of great help when using seaborn.